# Excel 2013 VBA multiple userforms to fill out the table

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on simple excel application for multiple users who will enter the data during different stages of the process. Unfortunately I met the problems with storage the data from multiple userforms in one row of the table.

I will try to explain what is the whole thing about as clear as I can.

For example purposes I called the application "Movie Time Control". Let's imagine that it is a tool for controlling the movies watched with focus on:

- when the movie started,
- if there were some breaks during displaying (and why)
- when the movie has been restarted (how long the break took, and how many breaks there were and what actions were taken to continue),
- in case when the movie was aborted, when, and why?
- when the movie ended.

The MENU of application segment will look as on the screenshot below:

[image]

For each button different userform is assigned. The data entered in each form should be stored in **one row in specific sheet**.

**Functionality of the userforms:**

1. MOVIE START: Creating the entry in the table with movie title, date and time when its started.
2. MOVIE BREAK: Based on the movie title previously defined, filling out the  date and time, reason of break (from the drop-down list or text box if not standard). The function can be used up to three times (three breaks).
3. MOVIE RESTART: If the break occurred, filling out the information about the date, time when movie was restarted, and what action has been taken in order to deal with the previously defined reason of break. For each break (possible three) function can be used.
4. MOVIE ABORT When (date and time) movie has been aborted (without intention to continue).
5. MOVIE FINISHED When (date and time) movie ended.

**Where the problems occurred (questions):**

1. When the data from the first row are entered, the entry with the specific title is created in the table separate sheet. Based on this entry, Title Combobox in all other userforms should list the titles which were started but not finished or aborted - just to quickly choose the "open title" and fill out other information related to the title. **How to create a macro to list the "open cases" in the combobox?**
2. I couldn't find out how to transfer the rest of the data to the same row of the table but different columns from all the forms after creating the entry with the specific movie title. Important thing is that the data can be added only to  row with corresponding title (chosen from combobox from first question). **Could you help me with the macro?**

---

**Macros** I created until now (I am very beginner with VBA, thanks for understanding):

MOVIE START: For creating the entry with movie title.

```
Private Sub movie_start_save_Click()

If MsgBox("ARE YOU SURE?", vbYesNo, "Please confirm") = vbYes Then

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet2 active
Sheet2.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Movie_Title_Box.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Start_Date_Box.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Start_Time_Box.Value
'Closing the form
Unload Me
'Back to MENU
Sheet1.Select
End If
End Sub


Private Sub movie_start_cancel_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub
```

MOVIE BREAK: For defining the time and reason (cannot transfer the data):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Fill ReasonComboBox
With ReasonComboBox
    .AddItem "Tea"
    .AddItem "Coffee"
    .AddItem "Popcorn"
    .AddItem "Dinner"
    .AddItem "Not standard"
End With

'Default text in the reason box
ReasonTextBox.ForeColor = &HC0C0C0 '<~~ Grey Color
    ReasonTextBox.Text = "In case of 'not standard' reason leave your comment here"
    movie_break_cancel.SetFocus '<~~ This is required so that the focus moves from TB

End Sub
'Default text in the reason box - disapearing when you want to edit
Private Sub ReasonTextBox_Enter()
    With ReasonTextBox
        If .Text = "In case of 'not standard' reason leave your comment here" Then
            .ForeColor = &H80000008 '<~ Black Color
            .Text = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
'Default text in the reason box - somehow disappearing for good, but ok
Private Sub ReasonTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    With ReasonTextBox
        If .Text = "" Then
            .ForeColor = &H80000008
            .Text = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub

'Cancel Button
Private Sub movie_break_cancel_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub
```

The rest is actually similar with a few differences.

---

**Link to download the excel file:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxFSL2h-9qflQjRzNTQ2ZlhJNjA/view?usp=sharing

Hopefully I expressed myself clear enough to understand this. 
Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example below, I show how to configure a ComboBox to hold multiple columns of data and to later retrieve the values.   This will allow you to store the Row number along with the movie data in the ComboBox.

'Filtering for not finished jobs for combobox
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim x As Long

```
    With Me.Movie_Title_ComboBox
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .ColumnWidths = "0 pt;250 pt;90 pt; 90 pt;"
        '.ListWidth = 500
        .TextColumn = 2
        .BoundColumn = 1
    End With

    Set ws = Sheet2
    With ws
        For x = 2 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(x, 4).Value = "" Then
                AddItems Me.Movie_Title_ComboBox, x, .Cells(x, 1).Value, Format(.Cells(x, 3).Value, "MM/DD/YYYY"), Format(.Cells(x, 3).Value, "HH:MM")
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Movie_Title_ComboBox_Change()
    With Me.Movie_Title_ComboBox
        If .ListIndex > -1 Then
            Finish_Date_Box.Value = .List(.ListIndex, 2)
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub movie_finished_save_Click()
    With Sheet2
        .Cells(Me.Movie_Title_ComboBox.Value, 4) = Me.Finish_Date_Box.Value
        .Cells(Me.Movie_Title_ComboBox.Value, 5) = Me.Start_Time_Box.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Add this function to a Public Code Module so that it will be available to all your userforms.

```
Sub AddItems(oComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox, ParamArray Items() As Variant)
    Dim x As Long

    With oComboBox
        .AddItem Items(0)
        For x = 1 To UBound(Items)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, x) = Items(x)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works very nice, but I'm still having some troubles: 1. When the movie is aborted, I would like to add the text "aborted" in cells with finish date/time, to make the position disappeared from the ComboBox list. 2. In case of second break during the movie, I don't know how to go automatically to the next columns (I have a space for three breaks in a table). Could you help me with this?

Comment: I decided to add dependent Combobox with the reasons of movie break. Unfortunately I am lost with getting the value from the first Combobox - "myval = Me.Combobox.Column(1)" does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: `Movie_Title_ComboBox.List(Movie_Title_ComboBox.ListIndex, 1)` will give you the value of the first column of the selected item. `Movie_Title_ComboBox.List(Movie_Title_ComboBox.ListIndex, 3)` will give you the value of the third column of the selected item.